# This struct is defined, so why does the function think it isn't?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, struct, undefined

New to C++. Just making a simple struct/array program. Why can't I pass an array of structs like I intend to here?

```
int NumGrads();

int main()
{
      struct Student {
          int id;
          bool isGrad;
      }; 

    const size_t size = 2;
    Student s1, s2;
    Student students[size] = { { 123, true },
                             { 124, false } };

    NumGrads(students, size);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int NumGrads(Student Stu[], size_t size){

}
```

I appreciate that it must be something to do with passing by either reference or value, but surely if I've defined it in main(), I shouldn't be getting an error with the parameter of NumGrads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Student` is defined in `main()`.
Define it outside of main so that it's in the same scope as `NumGrads`:

```
 struct Student
 {
      int id;
      bool isGrad;
 };

 int main()
 {
      ...
 }
```

Answer (score 12):

Your struct is defined *inside* your `main`, and your `NumGrads` function is defined *outside* of `main`.

This means your struct is defined outside the scope of where your function can see it.

Move the definition of your struct above `main` and your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

The struct definition is local to `main`. Nothing outside of `main` can see it, including your `NumGrads` definition. Having a struct definition inside a function is not a very common thing to do - typically you would have it at namespace scope.

Also your `NumGrads` declaration doesn't agree with the argument types of the definition.

```
// Define Student at namespace scope
struct Student {
    int id;
    bool isGrad;
}; 

int NumGrads(Student[], size_t); // The argument types are now correct

int main()
{
    // ...
}

int NumGrads(Student Stu[], size_t size){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`struct Student` is declared inside of main, so `int NumGrads` cannot see it. Furthermore, the function is undeclared at the point you call it in `main`. At that point, the only available declaration is `int NumGrads()`, which is a different function.